# Where can I find some of the basic functions in the framework(Laravel)? e.g. the basic() in Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth

Tags: laravel

I would like to know how some of the functions in the framework works, but I don't understand how they are declared and their locations. I would really want to dig into the deepest part and understand how it works.

In Laravel 5.7,  Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null, $field = null){

    $this->auth->guard($guard)->basic($field ?: 'email');

    return $next($request);
}
```

The 2 functions [guard() and basic()], is it possible to find where they are declare?

Comment: Using a proper IDE like PhpStorm, it should not be too hard. In other editors, that might get a bit more difficult as you have to watch out for the interface for `$this->auth` and open it on your own. After all, I don't think there is a generic approach

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.7

Comment: If you are using a decent IDE then https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper is also helpful